# Should I explicitly call init of class object in overridden descendant's init?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, super

In case with inheritance from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object) class whether it is necessary to explicitly call `__init__()` of `object` class (if `__init__()` of descendant is overridden)?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
```